# I'm getting error "The type or namespace name 'CS' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using component for cropping images. If I added to website it works fine. When I add it to web application project, I'm not able to compile it, getting the error below. Dll in bin folder, and I added reference to this DLL

```
Error   21  The type or namespace name 'CS' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?) E:\Site\CropImagePage.aspx.designer.cs  148 27  SiteName
```

Any idea what the reason why it's not compiling?

Comment: are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: I added to the project reference to that DLL.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring right now in your `.designer.cs.` I suspect you've got an out of date `.designer`.

- delete your CropImagePage.aspx.designer.cs . Don't worry, we'll get it back.
- build/run your site; this could eliminate the error.
- if you want it back, right click on CropImagePage.aspx, and select command 'Convert To Web Application'. This will recreate the .designer.cs.

Comment: I just did the way you suggested. and I still getting the same error